# How to solve "Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy" while fetching data from the API

Tags: reactjs, api

I looked up tons of similar questions but neither of their solutions helped me.

I am creating a React application and here trying to fetch the data from my university's library API. As it has XML format, I am using XMLParser to convert it to json. Here is how I am doing that:

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

const fetchBook = async() => {
     setLoading(true);
     try {
       /* fetching from the library api */
       const result= await axios.get("https://mylibrary.com/API", {"method": 'HEAD', "mode": 'no-cors', "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"});
       let xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(result);
       console.log(xml);
       setBook(xml);
     }
     catch(error) {
       setError(true);
     }
     setLoading(false);
   };
```

However, it takes up to a minute for a page to load and then it gives me two errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mylibrary.com/API' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and

> GET https://mylibrary.com/API net::ERR_FAILED

I've tried to add the method, mode and content-type thing like the following:

```
 {"method": 'HEAD', "mode": 'no-cors', "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8"}
```

but it didn't work either.

I'm not sure what else I can do to solve this problem. Would appreciate greatly for any help!

Comment: Your university appears to be blocking requests from your domain (in this case, `localhost:3000`). Presumably, this isn't a publicly available API, and you'll have to supply some sort of credentials to query it; and/or, it expects requests to originate from the same domain as its host. For example: User clicks a button that generates a request from `https://mylibrary.com` to `https://mylibrary.com/API`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to access APIs which are not public.
Only way you can access these APIs is by configuring your web url/domain "htp://localhost:3000" as part of enableCORS (In API Code). Which is really a bad idea.

In case if you have the API code locally available, You can enableCORS and use it.